# Determine if a generic class type needs to be instantiated

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class `Data<T>` which I use to store data received on a communication link.  The `Data<T>` class contains a `Value` property of type `T` and a `Timestamp` property of type `DateTime`.

Is it possible to determine in the class constructor that the requested type's default value is `null`, and in that case instantiate it?

I've looked at the `new()` class constraint.  But then I'm having trouble using the class with a string type, as I'm getting errors about string not having a parameterless constructor.

Here's an example causing a NullReferenceException on `dataValue4.Value`, since the `Value` property of type `Foo` is not instantiated.

```
public class Data<T> {
    public Data() {
        _timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private T _value;
    public T Value {
        get { return _value; }
        set { 
            _value = value;
            _timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _timestamp;
    public DateTime Timestamp {
        get { return _timestamp; }
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public bool Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {

        var dataValue1 = new Data<int>();
        var dataValue2 = new Data<bool>();
        var dataValue3 = new Data<string>();
        var dataValue4 = new Data<Foo>();
        //dataValue4.Value = new Foo();

        Console.WriteLine(dataValue1.Value);  // Output is "0"
        Console.WriteLine(dataValue2.Value);  // Output is "False"
        Console.WriteLine(dataValue3.Value);  // Output is ""
        Console.WriteLine(dataValue4.Value.Value1);  // Output is "0"
        Console.WriteLine(dataValue4.Value.Value2);  // Output is "False"
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually looks like you want `Foo` to be a `struct` instead of a `class`.  You could force the `Data` constructor to take a `T`, but you're still going to have to create the `Foo` outside the `Data` class because you just will not know what the constructor for `T` needs.

Comment: Does question marked as duplicate answers your question?

Comment: @Evk It actually helped me to find a working solution, but I wouldn't say my question is "an exact duplicate" as stated in the message.  I want to add my solution as an answer, but I cannot.  Is it because the question is marked?

Comment: Yes, but I reopened it, because also feel it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a instance with Activator.

```
var type = typeof(T);
var value = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as T;
```

This will create a instance with the default value of the type.

Comment: How can this be used with value types?  It says I have to use a `class` constraint on the class, which then causes errors when trying to use the class with value types.

Comment: That's not the best way with value types, try `default(T)` instead